# Shifting the default text position in NSIS installer pages

Tags: nsis

I am using a background image for my installer pages, I have set all the other controls transparent. 
There is a logo in the background image , which is overlapping with text on installer pages like the text on welcome page, license page etc.

So is it possible that I can shift the position of this text and its header from default to the one suitable for me, so that my background logo gets visible? Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use ResHacker and edit the UI .exe file you use (not you resulting .exe but .exe in NSIS\Contrib\UIs\ [which UI file to use depends on your script])

Move the header labels (controls with ID: 1037 and 1038) by a few pixels into desired position.
See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/izBby.jpg

[image: ResHacker with opened UI file]